# How to fix Designer code when relocating a control to a custom namespace

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a project with a custom control overriding a default control from the `system.windows.forms` namespace. This works fine, but I discovered I needed to modify a DLL this project depends on with some code that needs to know about the existence of this custom class; this code uses the class name of the control to do various things.

As the project depends on the DLL, and circular dependencies are not-a-good-idea, I moved the custom class to a third DLL which is a new project by cut-and-paste, and set the project and library to depend on this new lib, and set this new library to be built first, before the two other projects, and added an assembly reference.

So far so good; I can now import this new namespace and use it in my code. But, now the existing uses of the custom control are broken in any 'designer' based code, as they still point to the default namespace. I've tried adding a reference under Project Properties > Imported namespaces, yet this is insufficient: the code likely **needs** to contain the explicit line `imports <myNamespace>`. And while this is no-problem for regular files, when you have a designer file it's important to not manually modify it.

What's the easiest proper way of informing visual studio that any custom control named say `X` should now be accessed as `myNamespace.X`?

Answer (score 0):

The procedure as done in the question is correct, with one caveat: Check the .NET version, and if different set the target version to the lowest common denominator. If you use a newer Visual Studio than the original that was used to make the solution, it's likely there's a newer .NET out as well. By default, the latest .NET will be used for new projects. Visual studio will also happily attempt to build the projects with disparate .NET versions, and complain that it can't find references, then surreptitiously hide the version mismatch as a "Warning", even though linking assemblies with different targets is by default impossible.

The designer will then happily accept the custom class even if it's defined in another project.